# Why can't I pack these ints together?

Tags: c++

I have the following code. The goal is to combine the two `uint32_t`s into a single `uint64_t` and then retrieve the values.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    uint32_t first = 5;
    uint32_t second = 6;

    uint64_t combined = (first << 32) | second;

    uint32_t firstR = combined >> 32;
    uint32_t secondR = combined & 0xffffffff;

    std::cout << "F: " << firstR << "  S: " << secondR << std::endl;
}
```

It outputs

```
F: 0  S: 7
```

How do I successfully retrieve the values correctly?

Comment: You should try using a compiler that detects your programming bug, all by itself, and scolds you for making it: `warning: left shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]`. That would be gcc, of course. Your `int` is 32 bits, as such your left shift operation operates on a 32 bit value, and overflows. Explicitly cast `first` to a `uint64_t`, before shifting it. And switch to gcc, the best compiler in the entire universe, not just this world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform `first << 32`, you are shifting 32 bits within the space of 32 bits, so there are no bits remaining after the shift.  The result of the shift is 0.  You need to convert the `first` value to 64 bits before you shift it:

```
uint64_t combined = (uint64_t(first) << 32) | second;
```

Answer (score 2):

`first` is a 32-bit type and you bit-shift it by 32 bits. This is technically undefined behaviour, but probably the most likely outcome is that the result of the expression is 0. You need to cast it to a larger type before bit-shifting it.

```
uint64_t combined = (static_cast<uint64_t>(first) << 32) | second;
```

Comment: Upvoting this answer instead of the remaining two because of usage of `static_cast<>` instead of C-style casting

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    uint32_t first = 5;
    uint32_t second = 6;

    uint64_t combined = (uint64_t(first) << 32) | second;

    uint32_t firstR = combined >> 32;
    uint32_t secondR = combined & 0xffffffff;

    std::cout << "F: " << firstR << "  S: " << secondR << std::endl;
}
```

The bit manipulation operators return a type of the first parameter. So you need to cast it to `uint64_t` in order for it to have room for the `second` value.